# How to store localized text data in Unity?

Tags: unity, data, file, json, localization

I need to create a lot of read-only text data. As far as I know storing a lot of data directly in the script is not good, so I need to create a separate json file with ready-made data to load in the game.

But what if this data should be in multiple languages, that's where the question arises. Should I store in the json file the localization table's keys with translations to access the desired field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity has built-in support for storing localization data.  Import the localization package from Unity's package manager, and check out the [Quick Start Guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.localization@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuide.html).

It supports localization for `TextMeshPro`, `RawImage`, and `AudioSource`.

Populate your localization database, then right-click on the localizable component, and select Localize.  Then you can choose the localization asset.

If you need more custom localization, you can use [Smart Strings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.localization@1.3/manual/Smart/SmartStrings.html).
You can also use Smart Strings to serialize/deserialize classes/structs, although I suspect you took a wrong turn somewhere if you need to do that.

Comment: I don't think that using only localization tables I can reach my goal, because I need to have a structures of data that represent a class, so strings with integers and so on

Comment: If you'd like to know how you can implement that feature, you should post a new question describing that feature in detail.

Comment: @Silz that sounds like you are mixing things. A value of 4 should be the same regardless what language you are using. Game/ Business logic should not be stored in the translation

Comment: @Zibelas I know, but all strings is a part of a class, text itself doesn't make any sence, only visualize information to player